# Submit iPhone app to different countries

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know if you can submit an iPhone app to several countries rather than just your own?

thanks,

fbr

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, when you do the submission one of the form pages asks you which countries the app should be listed in.

Comment: can we change countries while updating the app?

Answer (score 3):

Yep, it happens by default.  My first sales were outside of the US.  At that point I realized that localizing my strings was going to be my next step.